# Updating GridView from Code behind. Cannot get hold of the data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am updating a GridView (JobCardStatusGridView) from code behind and although I get hold of the row index, I can't get hold of the data. here is my code.

```
protected void JobCardStatusGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int jobCardId = int.Parse((JobCardStatusGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("JobCardID") as TextBox).Text);
    string completedDate = (JobCardStatusGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CompletedData") as TextBox).Text;

    CrewController crewManager = new CrewController();
    crewManager.UpdateJobCard(jobCardId, completedDate);

    JobCardStatusGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    PopulateRouteStatus();
}
```

Here is my Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
      {
          PopulateRouteStatus();
      }
}
```

the error I receive from the variable jobCardId is Input *string was not in a correct format*. When I comment that line, the error I receive from the variable completedDate is *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* that led me to conclude that my code does not get hold of the data. And the strangest thing is that I get hold if the row index.
Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?
I now notice something that puzzled me more. If I populate the GridView each time the Page load, I retrieve the jobCardId variable. But when I prevent the GridView to be populated when there is a postback, for me to be able to retrieve the data, I get the errors mentioned above. I don't really understand.
Did someone figure out what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Could you post some markup to show how your `GridView` is composed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `jobCardId` the error means that the string you're trying to parse an integer from doesn't actually contain a valid integer.

For `completedDate` you have written `.FindControl("CompletedData")` instead of `.FindControl("CompletedDate")` - it should be 'e' instead of 'a'.

You can try more elegant way of finding the ID and Textbox value from Gridview from below code.

Try this:

```
protected void JobCardStatusGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)JobCardStatusGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     int jobCardId = Int32.Parse(JobCardStatusGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

     TextBox completedDate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("CompletedData");

   CrewController crewManager = new CrewController();
   crewManager.UpdateJobCard(jobCardId, completedDate);

   JobCardStatusGridView.EditIndex = -1;
   PopulateRouteStatus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that completedDate error. those kind are the worst to find. But I still have issue pulling the JobCardID. i tried the the code you gave and it didn't work. here is the error I got: *Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*

Comment: I found my mistake. i was changing the visible state on the TemplateField control instead of the TextBox control. I fixed it and it works now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @J.RaoulFEZE I am glad it helped :)